# Jquery/Javascript check input fields on keyboard touch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been googling to get an answer, but i couldn't find what i want. Not sure if i typed my question wrong, but i'll try to explain.

What i'm looking to achieve is : Once the user types, i want my script to run, so my button enables when the 2 passwords are equal to eachother. As soon as the passwords are equal to eachother, the button will be enabled. If not, the button will be disabled.

```js
function test123() {
       var pw1 = $('#pw1').val();
       var pw2 = $('#pw2').val();

       if (pw1 == pw2) {
             console.log('Valid!');
         } else {
             console.log('Not valid!');
         }

         }
```

```html
<div id='register-div'>
       <form method='POST' action='javascript:test123()'>
           <input name='username' type='text' placeholder='username'>
           <input id='pw1' name='password' type='password' placeholder='password'>
           <input id='pw2' name='password2' type='password' 
           placeholder='password_again'>
           <button type='submit'><a> REGISTER </a></button>
   </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: use `$('button').prop('disabled',true)` or false

Comment: I've got that figured out, my question is, how do i run a function when a key is pressed?

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this you can bind an `input` event to the password fields using unobtrusive JS. You can then enable/disable the button if the values match using `prop('disabled')`, like this:

```js
$('#pw1, #pw2').on('input', function() {
  var pw1 = $('#pw1').val();
  var pw2 = $('#pw2').val();

  $('button').prop('disabled', pw1 != pw2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="register-div">
  <form method="POST">
    <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
    <input id="pw1" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
    <input id="pw2" name="password2" type="password" placeholder="password_again">
    <button type="submit" disabled="true">REGISTER</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also note that I removed the `<a>` element you placed inside the `<button>`, as that is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $('#pw1,#pw2').keyup( function() {
    test123();
});
    function test123() {
           var pw1 = $('#pw1').val(),
             pw2 = $('#pw2').val();

           if (pw1 == pw2) {
                $('button').prop('disabled',false)
             } else {
                $('button').prop('disabled',true)
             }

             }
```

Comment: Just to add - It is better to bind on 'input' event than 'keyup' in this case so we prevent not needed firing when 'dummy' buttons are pressed and eventually capture clipboard pastes not done via buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```js
function test123() {
       var pw1 = $('#pw1').val();
       var pw2 = $('#pw2').val();

       if (pw1 == pw2) {
             document.getElementById("submit_btn").disabled = false;  
         } else {
             document.getElementById("submit_btn").disabled = true;  
         }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='register-div'>
       <form method='POST' action='javascript:test123()'>
           <input name='username' type='text' placeholder='username'>
           <input id='pw1' name='password' type='password' placeholder='password'>
           <input id='pw2' name='password2' type='password' 
           placeholder='password_again' onkeyup='test123()'>
           <button type='submit' id='submit_btn' disabled><a> REGISTER </a></button>
   </form>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').prop('disabled', true)
$('input.pass').on('input', function() {
  var pw1 = $('#pw1').val()
  var pw2 = $('#pw2').val()
  if (pw1 == pw2) {
    $('button').prop('disabled', false)
  } else {
    $('button').prop('disabled', true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='register-div'>
  <form method='POST' action='javascript:test123()'>
    <input name='username' type='text' placeholder='username'>
    <input class="pass" id='pw1' name='password' type='password' placeholder='password'>
    <input class="pass" id='pw2' name='password2' type='password' placeholder='password_again'>
    <button type='submit'><a> REGISTER </a></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

1. Add event handler on the input with same class pass
2. Use event `input`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test123() {
   var pw1 = $('#pw1').val();
   var pw2 = $('#pw2').val();
   if (pw1 == pw2) {
  $('button').prop('disabled',false)
   } else {
   $('button').prop('disabled',true)
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='register-div'>
 <form method='POST' action=''>
  <input name='username' type='text' placeholder='username'>
  <input id='pw1' onkeyup="return test123();" name='password' type='password' placeholder='password'>
  <input id='pw2' onkeyup="return test123();" name='password2' type='password' placeholder='password_again'>
  <button disabled type='submit'><a> REGISTER </a></button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple...you can use onkeypress event

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp